# webtest file opens as xml in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Community. I am doing GettingStartedWithLoadTesting. I am trying to open the SampleWebTest.webtest file but it opens as xml. It does not open how it did on the school computer. I think the school computer has Visual Studio Enterprise.  I tried "open with" but there was no option available for Load Testing Editor.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: double click the .sln file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio community does not support Web Performance and Load tests. For those you need the "Ultimate" or "Enterprise" versions.

The trial version of Visual Studio Enterprise can open `.webtest` and `.loadtest` files, but there are restrictions on the run-time features of these test types.

Answer (score 1):

If you install Visual Studio by WebInstaller, you can miss "test components". You can always add it. Just start the installer again and pick "change" for your version of visual studio.